# Expected value of inverse of complex non-central Wishart matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices, expectation

I have a matrix $W$ that abides a complex non-central Wishart distribution.
My question is what the expectation of the inverse is, i.e., how to compute
$$\mathbb{E}(W^{-1}).$$

I have tried to read up on this, but am unable to find the answer anywhere. The distribution of $W^{-1}$ is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1799 (Corollary 3.2), but I am unable to get the expectation.

Since different authors use different notation, I write out explicity how $W$ is formed:
$$W=Y^\ast Y$$
where
$$Y=A+Z,$$ where $A$ is a deterministic (known) matrix, and $Z$ is a matrix comprising complex normal random variables, each row with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $(\cdot)^\ast $ denotes transpose and complex conjugation. The matrix $Y$ is tall (i.e., more rows than columns).

Comment: I don't think the expectation of $W^{-1}$ with $W=Y^\ast Y$ exists, because $Y$ can become zero with finite probability.